# How can I use public-key encryption for luks?

Tags: security, encryption, ecryptfs

I have been running **luks** with the following commands:

```
$ sudo dd if=/dev/urandom of=/keyfile bs=1024 count=4
$ sudo cryptsetup luksFormat /dev/XXX keyfile
$ sudo cryptsetup luksDump /dev/XXX
```

And it shows me as following message:

```
Version:        1
Cipher name:    aes
Cipher mode:    cbc-essiv:sha256
Hash spec:      sha1
Payload offset: 4096
MK bits:        256
MK digest:      f3 79 af 60 e6 34 5c 6e 27 6a e4 fe b6 f0 b2 95 8a 85 5c 31 
MK salt:        14 33 6b 95 f8 3d a9 e2 84 67 85 a1 18 be 70 58 
                af 10 10 28 c5 5b d1 1a 31 8e 8f e1 5a 93 51 12 
MK iterations:  45250
UUID:           776d4a78-3487-42df-8d3c-38708fdea60d

Key Slot 0: ENABLED
    Iterations:             181146
    Salt:                   da cf b7 36 fc 98 7c 5c 73 68 ca 44 f4 00 55 52 
                            47 46 68 50 bf aa 2e bb ac 47 83 0f 76 05 a6 05 
    Key material offset:    8
    AF stripes:             4000
```

According to the output, *Cipher name* is **aes** and it is not *public key encryption*. Is it used to encrypt just the **master key**, or does it encrypt **contents** too? If it only encrypts the **master key**, how is **contents** encrypted?

I'm sure **aes** also very secure. But I think that *public key encryption* is more secure than other methods such as **aes**. Thus, I tried to find out how to use **gpg** or any other encryption methods for **luks** at the man page of *cryptsetup*, but I could not find a solution.

How can I use **public-key encryption** for *luksFormat*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Public key encryption is really only useful if you want to have other people encrypt messages to you, and you don't want to go to the trouble of secretly giving them your secret encryption key. So you post your public key for the world to see and encrypt messages to you, that only you can read.

It would be of no benefit to you personally encrypting your files on your own computer. It could be assumed that public key encryption is *less* secure than conventional encryption (like AES, Blowfish, Camellia...) since you're handing out part of the encryption information (the public part). Though in practice they are both effectively "unbreakable" in any human lifetime.

And you may not know how the public-key encryption program PGP/GPG actually works, it **conventionally** encrypts messages, and then encrypts the conventional key using **public key encryption**.

Here's a quote from some older (but still valid) [PGPi documentation](http://www.pgpi.org/doc/pgpintro/#p10) explaining it, and a bit about why someone may think one method is more secure than the other, if they're only comparing key sizes:

> > PGP combines some of the best features of **both conventional and public key cryptography**. PGP is a hybrid cryptosystem. When a user encrypts plaintext with PGP, PGP first compresses the plaintext. Data compression saves modem transmission time and disk space and, more importantly, strengthens cryptographic security. Most cryptanalysis techniques exploit patterns found in the plaintext to crack the cipher. Compression reduces these patterns in the plaintext, thereby greatly enhancing resistance to cryptanalysis. (Files that are too short to compress or which don't compress well aren't compressed.)
> >
> > PGP then creates a session key, which is a one-time-only secret key. This key is a random number generated from the random movements of your mouse and the keystrokes you type. This session key works with a very secure, fast **conventional encryption algorithm** to encrypt the plaintext; the result is ciphertext. Once the data is encrypted, the session key is then encrypted to the recipient's public key. This public key-encrypted session key is transmitted along with the ciphertext to the recipient.
> >
> > ...
> >
> > The combination of the two encryption methods combines the convenience of public key encryption with the speed of conventional encryption. **Conventional encryption is about 1,000 times faster than public key encryption**. Public key encryption in turn provides a solution to key distribution and data transmission issues. Used together, performance and key distribution are improved without any sacrifice in security.
> >
> > ...
> >
> > However, public key size and conventional cryptography's secret key size are totally unrelated. A conventional 80-bit key has the equivalent strength of a 1024-bit public key. A conventional 128-bit key is equivalent to a 3000-bit public key. Again, the bigger the key, the more secure, but the algorithms used for each type of cryptography are very different and thus comparison is like that of apples to oranges.

---

If you wanted to use some method involving GPG to use your public key to encrypt the passphrase or keyfile to your LUKS container, you could do that if you wanted. But then if your GPG private key were ever compromised or lost, so too would your LUKS container.

And you can choose a different cipher with cryptsetup, it would use the cipher to encrypt all the data. See `man cryptsetup` for info like:

```
   --cipher, -c <cipher-spec>
          Set the cipher specification string.
```

And under a default Ubuntu at least these ciphers should be supported:

loop-AES: aes, Key 256 bits
plain: aes-cbc-essiv:sha256, Key: 256 bits
LUKS1: aes-xts-plain64, Key: 256 bits

Comment: Per your last few paragraphs, if I wanted to use a GPG keypair to encrypt/decrypt my LUKS container, is there any way to have LUKS store the encrypted symmetric key (as it normally would for password encrypted keys). It seems like one has to manage the keyfile externally to LUKS if you want to add the additional asymmetric layer, in which case, one can just do plain dm-crypt and LUKS isn't really necessary.

Comment: @Endophage I'm just brainstorming some ideas...  You could use your GPG secret key file itself as a keyfile for LUKS, but it wouldn't ask for your secret gpg passphrase, so physical security of your secret keyfile is paramount, and if the file changed that's bad. I don't know how to get gpg to display the actual secret key data, requiring your passphrase, but a command like that could be piped to cryptsetup and used as a LUKS key. Or you could have a detached LUKS header (with `--header`) and then encrypt the header with GPG; but you'd still need to pick/enter a key/keyfile for LUKS.

Comment: @Endophage You can specify a binary key directly with `--hash plain` so cryptsetup won't hash the key, just zero pad or truncate it as a binary key. If you don't need LUKS's multiple keys, salt & hashing & header backups then plain dm-crypt would be good, and without an obvious LUKS header it would be more "plausibly deniable" that it's not encrypted too. I'd probably encrypt a random keyfile with gpg, and pipe it to cryptsetup as a keyfile; you could use `dd` to put/read the encrypted gpg file at the start of the cryptsetup container, and `--offset` with plain dm-crypt to avoid it...

Comment: My understanding is that the `--hash plain` with a `--keyfile` uses the key directly to encrypt the container. By that measure it wouldn't actually use the GPG keys as a keypair (or is there something special that recognizes GPG keys and uses them appropriately?).

Comment: "It would be of no benefit to you personally encrypting your files on your own computer." That's not entirely correct. For example, encrypting log files that may contain sensitive info with a public key guarantees that past log files cannot be read by an attacker gaining root access to the machine.

Comment: @Clément I was referring to using public key encryption, conventional encryption is definitely beneficial - I'm not seeing how public key encryption would be any better than conventional in your example, if the old files are conventionally encrypted they can't be read without the key anyway, or if the entire drive's (LUKS) encrypted then there's no root access without the key either.

Comment: Take the example of encrypting log files: you need the `apache` or `nginx` user (or whichever user writes the logs) to keep the key in memory, to be able to encrypt new logs.  If the machine is compromised, this key can be used to decrypt past logs.  OTOH, if you encrypt the logs asymmetrically, compromising the machine does not allow you to read previous logs.  Essentially, what public-key encryption gives you is a write-only file system.